# phpMyAdmin hangs during mySql file import

Tags: phpmyadmin

I received a bunch .sql files, none of them are > 200k I use phpMyAdmin in XAMMP to import to my DB at about 80% of successful import, the must be a bad .sql file that caused phpMyAdmin to hang, but there is no error massage whatsoever. How can phpMyAdim recover from this without erasing the already imported files?  BTW, I use XAMPP 1.7.3 for Mac
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As PMA is a web interface, it is limited to the same post size limits and timeout limits, etc, as any other web app.

If you have to import large files you will have to do them from the command line.

```
mysql -u username -p db_name < /path/to/importFile.sql
```

replace `username` with the DB username, `db_name` with the database name, and `/path/to/importFile.sql` with the full path to the import file.

If you have really large files, I would recommend [`Big Dump`](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/) which will stagger the upload. I've used this tool several times and it works very well and is easy to use.

Comment: this not allow me to create the database via sql import file.